# Which type of group is it when to create them?

Tags: group

There are two type of group concept in linux :primary vs secondary groups,it is simple to create a new group:

```
sudo groupadd gname
```

Now i want to know the new created group `gname` belongs to which type of group?Is there a way to inter-convert between them?

Create two new group which contain no user

```
sudo groupadd writers
sudo groupadd editers
```

Add new user.

```
sudo useradd -m mywriter -p yourpassword
sudo useradd -m myediter -p yourpassword
```

Add new user into group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G writers mywriter  
sudo usermod -g editers myediter
```

Now we get 4 groups.

```
cat /etc/group | tail -4 
writers:x:1007:mywriter
editers:x:1008:
mywriter:x:1009:
myediter:x:1010:
```

Enter into mywriter

```
$ touch /tmp/mywriter.txt
$ ls -al  /tmp/mywriter.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mywriter mywriter 0 Aug 23 21:24 /tmp/mywriter.txt
```

Enter into myediter

```
$ touch /tmp/myedier.txt
$ ls -al  /tmp/myediter.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myediter editers 0 Aug 23 21:27 /tmp/myediter.txt
```

For group1----mywriter:

```
id mywriter
uid=1009(mywriter) gid=1009(mywriter) groups=1009(mywriter),1007(writers)
```

It is a primary group `mywriter` since uid=gid=1009.

For group2--myediter

```
id myediter
uid=1010(myediter) gid=1008(editers) groups=1008(editers)
```

It is a secondary group?

How to classify group `writers` and `editers` ?

Comment: As the manual says, a group added using the `-g` option is the initial (or primary) group for the user, while groups added using the `-G` option are supplementary (or secondary) groups for the user. I think the missing piece here is `useradd`'s default behavior (its configuration depends on the system you are on): unless you tell it not to, it creates a group named after the new user and sets is as the initial (primary) group for that user. Here, you are leaving it unchanged for the `mywriter` user, while you are replacing it with `editers` for the `myediter` user.

Comment: How to classify group writers and editers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groups aren't, inherently, primary or secondary.  A group is just a group.

What matters is how they are used.

So let's take a typical login session.  (I'm gonna simplify this for ease of explanation, but the same logic applies in more complicated cases).

When the login process comes to set up your group memberships the first thing it does is look in the `passwd` file.

For me, on my machine:

```
sweh:x:500:500:Stephen Harris:/home/sweh:/bin/ksh
```

The second number determines the *primary* group.  So my primary group is group id 500.

The next thing it does is look at the group file, and see what entries have my username listed against them:

```
% grep -w sweh /etc/group
wheel:x:10:sweh
sweh:x:500:
apache:x:48:sweh
news:x:13:news,sweh
```

So we can see that I've been listed against groups 10, 48 and 13.  These are *secondary* groups.

We can see this with the `id` command:

```
% id
uid=500(sweh) gid=500(sweh) groups=500(sweh),10(wheel),13(news),48(apache)
```

The `gid` value lists the primary group.  The `groups` value lists *all* the groups I'm in.  Everything that isn't a primary is a secondary.

A different login might have different primary and secondary groups, based on their entry in `passwd` and `group`.

So we can see "primary" and "secondary" is based on the context of the *user* and how that user is defined.  It's not based on the group, itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's either: whether it is a *primary* or *secondary* group depends entirely on how you attach it to a given user-id.  Some systems have a [`usermod`](https://man.openbsd.org/usermod.8) program for instance which has an option to specify the group as a secondary group.